# Deleting a key from a dictionary that is in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries generated by:

```
    r=requests.get(url, headers={key:password})
    import_data_list.append(r.json())
```

I want to delete the first key from these dictionaries. I know I can delete the dictionaries in the list with:

```
    del import_data_list[0]
```

But how do I delete a key from the dictionary in the list, rather than deleting the whole dictionary.

I tried something like:

```
    del import_data_list[0["KEY"]]
```

Obviously it doesnt work!

Any help would be much appreciated and sorry if its a dumb question. Still learning!

Comment: _Be care for what you wish for_: If you are using python 3.5 and under, `dict` is **not** ordered and therefore you will not know what actually _is_ the first one.Which python are you on?

Comment: What about `del import_data_list[0]["KEY"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have this list of dictionaries.

```
myList = [
    {
        "Sub1List1" : "value",
        "Sub2List1" : "value",
        "Sub3List1" : "value",
        "Sub4List1" : "value"
    },
    {
        "Sub1List2" : "value",
        "Sub2List2" : "value",
        "Sub3List2" : "value",
        "Sub4List2" : "value"
    },
    {
        "Sub1List3" : "value",
        "Sub2List3" : "value",
        "Sub3List3" : "value",
        "Sub4List3" : "value"
    }
]
```

Now, if you want to delete key `Sub1List1` from the first list, you can do this by using :

```
del myList[0]["Sub1List1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the **first key** (you don't know its name, you just know it is the first one) from these dictionaries, I suggest you to loop over the dictionaries of the list. You can use `list(d.keys())[0]` or even `list(d)[0]` to get the first key of a dictionary called `d`.
Here is an example:

```
for d in import_data_list:
    k = list(d)[0]  # get the first key
    del d[k]        # delete it from the dictionary
print(import_data_list)
```

You can also do it with one-lined style using a list comprehension, which I find quite smart too. In this case you also retrieve the values of the first keys in a list, which might be useful:

```
r = [d.pop(list(d)[0]) for d in import_data_list]
print(import_data_list)
```

*Note that it works only with python version >= 3.6 (but not with version <= 3.5 because dictionaries are not ordered)*

Comment: why does del d[k] stay true without creating a new list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

```
del dictionaryName[KEY]
```